# How to store large buffer/array (char/int) using protocol buffer in cpp...?

Tags: c++, protoc, protocol-buffers

Is there any way to store array using google protocol buffer in cpp without using repeated. I need to store and send buffer (of size 640x480x2) consisting image data. Also how to store uint16_t array data using protocol buffer..?

Comment: Why don't you send your  image as it is, without additional packing it to varint (protocol buffer) ?

Comment: Actually I need to use protocol buffer to store image data and to send it over network.

Answer (score 1):

- In protobuf `repeated` = `array`. I don't see why you cannot use `repeated uint32 img = field_num`
- If you really want to store into a byte array, you can try `pb.set_mybytearray( std::string( data, data_length ) );`
- Protobuf does not support `uint16` : https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/proto3-spec#fields. I'd recommend to use the `uint32` type. Given that protobuf encodes values into varint the message will not contain 2 bytes of zeros.

Comment: I was trying to store int array containing image data using bytes.As bytes is arbitrary sequence of bytes. Could I use bytes to store int array data..?

Comment: Yes, you will have to convert each int to byte[4], and then create a string to set the byte array, as updated in the answer.